# Serve dynamic PDF generated by matplotlib in Flask

Tags: python, pdf, matplotlib, flask

I'm working on a simple online application, using Flask, which will get values from an HTML form, and generate a PDF plot based on these user-supplied values, using matplotlib.

All of this works, but now I'd like to produce a results page with html links which would allow the user to download this dynamically generated PDF. Ideally, this would imply serving it dynamically as opposed to storing it on the server as a static file (so that I don't end up with an archive of everybody's PDF, for reasons of privacy).

My Google-fu has failed me so far. Any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly is your question? Are you maybe looking for a pointer to   [`flask.send_file()`](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.send_file)? Whether the contents of the file are dynamically generate or not really doesn't make much of a difference.

Comment: May be you could try to store the generated PDF at a temporary folder and delete it once the user has downloaded the file. Just a suggestion. Hope it's useful.

Comment: `savefig` takes a file-like object so you can write the pdf into string buffer.  How to make that a flask download target is something I can not help you with.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how long it takes to generate the plots and the amount of concurrent requests you need to handle, you might need to implement a task queue to generate the plots. This will provide temporary storage for the PDFs at the same time. This can be implemented with [Celery](http://www.celeryproject.org), Redis and PostgreSQL, for example. Your online application will no longer be simple though.